# How can we write form validation for input type number in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Iam trying to write form validation to input type number,but Iam getting error message even Iam entering numbers also.Can we write form validation for input type="number"?Or is there any other way for declaration in angularjs?
Here is my code:

```html
<form name="validation">
<input type="number"  ng-model="cost" name="cost" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"><span ng-show="validation.cost.$error.pattern" style="color:red">Enter numbers only</span>
</form>
```

Comment: you can make the type text for input and it would work fine.

Comment: Yes.With input type="text",it is working.But for input type="number",it is not working.Is there any way for writing validation to input type="number"?

Comment: If you want the input to accept only numbers, the above code with type text would do. Do you have any other specific requirement other than accepting only numbers?

Comment: Yes.It has to accept  decimal values also

Comment: @srujana you need to use `validation.input.$error.pattern` in `ng-show`

Comment: ok.Thankyou for suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the regex for accepting both number and decimals. Just update  the regex to `/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/`. I have added a working fiddle for your understanding [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KGd8K/3227/).